# Returning the date depending on today's weekday in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I am new to report building with SSRS.
I am currently trying to have an expression in SSRS show a specific date depending on wether today's day is on a weekend or not. This I tried to achieve by utilizing the different date functions Microsoft provides in their documentation. This is what I got so far:

```
=IIF(WeekdayName(weekday(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, today()))) = 'Monday', CDate(DateAdd("d", -3, Parameters!DateTo.Value)), 
IIF(WeekdayName(weekday(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, today()))) = 'Sunday', CDate(DateAdd("d", -2, Parameters!DateTo.Value)),
CDate(DateAdd("d", -1, Parameters!DateTo.Value))))
```

As you can see I am trying to have it so if today's day is Sunday or Monday the date value returned should be the one from last Friday else it should return yesterday's date.

In Report Builder I'm receiving an error message stating that there is an expression expected and I cannot save the file.

What am I missing here? Is there maybe a different approach to achieving this? Thanks for any help.

BR,
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this... There may be more efficient ways but this would be my approach...

```
=IIF(
    Weekday(Today())=7 OR Weekday(Today())=1
    ,DATEADD(DateInterval.Day, (Weekday(Today())+1) * -1, Today())
    , Today()
    )
```

**Note** This assumes you week starts on a Sunday, if not adjust the first part of the `IIF` to suit.

So here we are saying...

If today is Saturday (7) or today is Sunday(1) then, subtract the (current day number +1) from the current date, else return the current date.